# QFP on stripboard, without PCB?

Tags: pcb, dip, stripboard, tqfp

Are there any tricks I can use to connect a QFP (or similar) package component to a stripboard (veroboard), without the hassle of setting up a personal PCB fabrication kit to make a breakout board?

I've seen TQFP-to-DIP adapters on places like Farnell, but they tend to be extortionate - some are over £80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Farnell *is* expensive, and we only use it because of its overnight delivery.

There are cheaper options. [EZPrototypes](http://www.ezprototypes.com/DipAdaptersMain.php) has for instance a QFP64 to DIL adapter for 10 dollar.

**edit**
Since you're in the UK, [HobbyTronics](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/tqfp-dip-adapter) has a QFP adapter for a mere GBP 3.

[image]

Not DIL though, so it won't fit on a solderless breadboard, but on Veroboard it will do.

Comment: Know of any alternatives to EZPrototypes? The shipping cost to the UK is ludicrous.

Comment: Excellent! I'm using veroboard, so this is perfect.

Comment: I hate Farnell.. Just hate..

Comment: @abdullah - You'll pay 4 times the price, but if you're working on a prototype you have to finish by tomorrow their overnight delivery is a godsend.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman - We use Farnell all the time. It would be hard to do our job without them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are patient or desperate, there is another solution, called "dead bug":

[image: dead bug]

This requires no additional materials except some wires and maybe some glue to fix the chip on the board but extraordinary soldering skill.

Comment: How about [this](http://elm-chan.org/docs/wire/wiring_e.html)? This one looks easy! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Buy a breakout board, such as those made by Schmartboard:

http://www.schmartboard.com/

I'd make my own, it's quite easy.

Comment: It's easy when you already have the equipment and experience. I have neither.